# How resolve Delphi Out Of Memory Error?

Tags: delphi

I am having one Delphi XE2 project to handle large numbers of calculations.
In my project i am having total 1290 Numbers of `Edit`, 340 Numbers of `Label`, 330 Numbers of `Panel`, 16 Numbers of `TabSheet`. For each and every `Edit`, there is `OnChange`, `OnDblClick`, `OnEnter` and `OnExit` events.

I have to handle total 1034 Numbers of `Variable`. I have just designed the `Form` and not added those calculation logic. Now my `.pas file` becomes `62.5MB` having **1815057 Lines** and `.dfm file` becomes `1.98 MB` having **65540 Lines**.

I am trying to compile the project using `Delphi XE2` under `Windows XP Professional SP3 32Bit`, but I am getting error as `**[DCC Fatal Error] Unit1.pas(1815058): F2046 Out of memory**`.

I have also tried to compile it using `Delphi XE5` under `Windows 8 Enterprise 64Bit`, here is also, I am getting the same problem.

I have not added the complete calculation logic using 1034 Numbers of variables, if I add them , at least **4200 Lines** will be added to the `.pas file`.

Comment: Well, what did you expect. You have a single source file with 1.8 million lines of code. You need to learn how to abstract things. Don't create 1200 edit controls in a .dfm file. Create them at run time. Create them only when the tab sheet is shown. Use a single `OnChange` event handler for all the edits. Switch behaviour on the `Sender` parameter. You need to learn how to abstract behaviour rather than hand code every single option. Just imagine what happens when you want to change something.

Comment: Your code stinks. :-) A single unit with 1.8M LOC is simply wrong, and so is having 1290 Edit controls - there's no way a user can see them, so they don't need to exist all the time. You need to seriously rethink your design. Nothing is going to fix your error until you actually make your code manageable. I wish you the best of luck, because you're going to need it. :-)

Comment: How did you generate the program? You cannot have written it by hand. You wrote a program to generate that code? Take the ideas of that program and make it happen at run time rather than as a pre-compile step.

Comment: I have designed using Microsoft Excel.

Comment: @user2612109: You used Excel **as a code generator**?  I'm not sure whether to be fascinated or horrified!

Comment: @Mason: It sure beats using Paintbrush as a code generator.

Comment: Yah, I have done it using Excel.

Comment: Fascinating to what purpose people use Excel. That's a real creative one, indeed.

Comment: I've used Excel to produce code, but certainly never that much code.

Comment: Excel really comes in handy when producing bulk SQL insert or update scripts too.

Comment: I routinely use Python (my scripting language of choice) to generate code.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your entire approach is flawed. The compiler simply cannot handle the size of file that you present it. A 1.8 million line pascal source file is ridiculous. A 2MB .dfm file is impractical.

It appears that you have coded all possible options as separate controls and variables. You've not written the code by hand, but have done so using a pre-processing step, in Excel.

The solution is not to expand all the options at compile time. The solution is to write the application so that it can present the different options at run time. So, where you have 30 different variables, you've probably created 30 different label controls, and 30 different edit controls. The correct approach is to create one label and one edit control. Then at run time, depending on the user's option, change the caption of the label, and the content of the edit control.

Don't create one variable for every possible value that you need to store. Use arrays and or dictionaries.

At a high level, you need to take the logic that is contained in your Excel pre-processing step and convert it into run time Delphi code.