# What is the maximum size of code the compiler can process?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

Is there a *(even a not realistic)* limit to the number of lines/size of code/etc that the compiler can accept and process? I could not find anything about this in the documentation.

Can we say that the ability to process the length/size of just one file is limited only by hardware?

Comment: Our software, just one exe, has over 3 million lines of code, but lines of code is a very vague subject in Delphi. I recall seeing just a very simple console application, stripping out all unnecessary code, seems to add one extra invisible line of code, which also happens on all other units. You also have to consider that Delphi / Pascal isn't line specific - you could condense 10 lines of code into 1.

Comment: Older versions of Delphi had a limit of 65536 LOC/unit, afaik.  Modern versions do not, but at some point you'll probably find that the amount of memory required to compile an overly large unit (orders of magnitude larger than anything sensible) will probably start severely impacting your compile times. A million LOC in one unit is much more taxing to compile than a million LOC spread out over many units.  If you keep your individual units to a sensible size then there isn't really a practical limit beyond the limitations of your hardware.

Comment: http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/hundred_thousand_lines_unit.html

Comment: Also, for amusement, this one always makes me laugh... http://stackoverflow.com/q/19082534/327083

Comment: Are you asking about size of code in a single unit? Or an entire project? Or perhaps a DFM/FMX file? Or all of the above?

Comment: It is always nice to have 1300 `Edits` :)
I know, having individual units help with this problem. But can we say that the ability to process the length/size of **just one** file is limited only by hardware?

Comment: @JerryDodge a single unit, for example.

Comment: AFAIK, Since files can be automatically saved as binary when they become too large to stay as plain text, the limit is tied to the hardware. I guess it also has a lot to do with how much memory the compiler is allowed to allocate. If I recall, one of the features of Delphi 10 Seattle is that the amount of memory it can handle has been doubled.

Comment: There will be a limit. As to what it is, it probably depends on a great many factors. Do you have a problem?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no limit to the number of lines a single unit can have.
Obviously, because Delphi is a 32-bit program you cannot exceed 2GB in any allocation.

However:

**1 IDE and compilation speed**
If you open a unit in Delphi the IDE will parse the unit and that will make the IDE slow.
It makes more sense to split a large project into multiple (mostly) self-contained units and have the compiler compile these.
Every unit will create a `.DCU` file, that the linker can use to put together the final exe.

If a unit matches the dcu, then Delphi will not recompile the unit, but just pass the dcu file to the linker.
This results in much faster compilation.

Even a single edit in a unit causes a full recompile of that unit.
In your hypothical huge unit that would take a long time.
It's also much lighter on any SVN system you might have.

**2 Compiler bugs**
Accidents and bugs happen. Sometimes the compiler does not grok otherwise OK code because of a bug.
In your million+ line unit that would be complicated, if you have smaller units it's easier to debug.
I would imagine it's also easier on the compiler to not trigger the bug conditions with smaller units.

**3 Sanity**
Smaller units lead to easier to maintain project.
If you put code that shares a functional relationship together in an unit the logical becomes easier to grok.
If you have smaller units, it's easier to reuse code from these in another project.

Comment: I'm sure there's a limit. For instance the number of atoms in the universe would provide one upper limit. I'm sure that smaller upper limits can be found. I suspect that you mean to say that no explicit limit is applied. But then, how can you know that is the case? Is it documented?

Comment: I'm echoing Macro Cantu, according to him there is no fixed limit.

Comment: What does "you cannot exceed 2GB in any allocation" mean? A 32 bit address space is 4GB in size. Why are single allocations relevant? You don't need to keep the source file in contiguous memory. It's perfectly possible to compile a program that does not fit in memory. In the olden days all compilers did that. I suppose a lot of what I am getting at is that is seems a little like you are making some of this up. Without clear references to official documentation or statements, and without being an Embarcadero engineer, how can you make these claims?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Until Delphi 10 Seattle the IDE was basically limited to 2 GB of memory because older versions of the IDE did not use `large memory address model` as Delphi 10 Seattle does now. Also you have to realize that Delphi IDE needs to contain large portion of the source code inside memory in order for some of its features to work. Two of the most know such features are Code insight and Error insight. ...

Comment: @SilverWarior Yes, I know this.

Comment: ... You also need to realize that IDE has to store many other things than just code inside memory. If you have an application with lots of visual components each of these components requires some more memory space even in design time. Also various plugins that can be installed into Delphi in order to expand its functionality also require their own chunk of memory. So it is impossible to say exactly how many lines of code can Delphi IDE handle. ...

Comment: ... During the `RAD Studio 10 Seattle Deep Dive Session` one of the presenters mentioned approximate number of lines that newest Delphi should be able to handle but I can't remember what was it. You can find this out by watching the replays that are available here: http://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/rad-studio-10-seattle-deep-dive-session-replays-now-on-youtube

Comment: Thanks, @SilverWarior! I´ll continue my researches and will inform you if I find something.